# Unable to load script from another server - Content Security Policy issue?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bookmarklet

I have been trying to turn a bookmarklet into a small development environment that I can use for testing some javascript and sending commands easily on the fly and updating the code on my server quickly to see the result.  This has half way worked using method's I have found in this site and google however it doesn't seem to work very well and sometimes randomly doesn't work.  The end goal is to have a bookmarklet that I can click on from any page and it loads a javascript file I have saved on my server.  I have created the following two bookmarklets to try and get this working:

Failed Method 1:

```
javascript:
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type='text/javascript';
document.body.appendChild(s);
s.src='//smewth.com/test.js';
void(0);
```

Method 1 in one line bookmarklet form:  `javascript: var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type='text/javascript'; document.body.appendChild(s); s.src='//smewth.com/test.js'; void(0);`

---

Failed Method 2:

```
javascript:(
 function(){
  var imported = document.createElement('script');
  imported.type='text/javascript';
  imported.src = 'https://smewth.com/test.js';
  document.head.appendChild(imported);
})();
```

Method 2 in one line bookmarklet form:  `javascript:( function(){ var imported = document.createElement('script'); imported.type='text/javascript'; imported.src = 'https://smewth.com/test.js'; document.head.appendChild(imported); })();`

I got method 1 by decomposing the kickass bookmarklet from (http://kickassapp.com/).  The actual one I got from their site works fine on my browser no problems.  I even did a direct substitution from the URL they were using to load with my URL.  The second method I found while searching on this site and this actually worked for a small while and stopped working for some unknown reason (maybe different browsers).  I tried appending this script object to the head and the body on each of them with no improved results.

I created the test.js script just for this post and it contains a simple alert box statement:

```
$$ [/]# cat test.js
alert("hi");
$$ [/]#
```

NOTE:  When I do this with the code embedded within the the bookmarklet itself without appending it to a head/body object then it works fine such as this:

```
javascript:%20alert("hi");
```

I did notice that with both of these methods, the  code is actually getting injected into the page however I am not seeing the code is ever executed when I click the bookmark.  Does anyone know which method is the best or something similar to do this so I can have javascript load through a page which I update on a remote server (reliably)?  Maybe I need to attach the  to a different object?

Thank you for your help.

-Jeff

UPDATE:  I am showing this works while this site is loaded but it doesn't work when your at a site like google.com.  Not sure what the difference is or how to accomodate this, google.com has a head and a body object too.  I am showing this works in some sites and in some it doesn't.

Comment: This might be due to **Content Security Policy** but that doesn't explain why I am able to load the kickass bookmarklet on google.com and I can't load the one I made on it.

Comment: Are you running into a XSS error or a CSP error in the browser? You likely want to use JSONP to bypass if it's XSS.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm actually not showing any errors in the browser.  After I click the bookmark, I am showing the <script> tags do show up in the source.  But for some reason the contents of the <script> are not evaluated.

Comment: @CHBuckingham, Due to your update, I double checked other browsers for errors which ultimately led to resolution.  Firefox is really bad at reporting errors in the console for applications such as this.  In Chrome the errors were there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  There were two things occurring which accounts for the intermittent symptom of this issue.  The first issue was that the site which was hosting the code was on a self-signed certificate.  I began to notice the issue was occurring only when trying to run this from within secure sites.  Then in Chrome I saw a error show up in the console.   It would be nice if Firefox gave me a error on the console or something as this was the root of the issue.  The second thing I had to do was disable OCSP in Firefox as I used a free certificate for testing purposes.

I also had to use method 1 as described above.  Firefox and Chrome both did not like the anonymous function call for some reason.  From now on I will refer to Chrome to look for errors in the console as Firefox has proven itself not very useful for this.